# how to draw a click polygon vue-konva

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, konvajs, vue-konva

How can I draw a polygon where I can set each corner with a click with vue konva ?
I couldn't find anything a side from `v-polygon` which creates a predefined polygon and not an interactive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement the whole thing thanks to this thread/issue in the vue-konva repo
https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva/issues/104